# How can forever monitor service stop and restart automatically

Tags: node.js

Previously, i use `forever start xxx.js` to start a service;

Today I saw a service that  `stopped`. I don't know why,

Can forever automatically monitor the service operation like docker, and restart the service when it stops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forever.js` is made to restart the process whenever it fails. some crashes might not be able to recover immediately, that's when you need to fix the fault first.

Anyways, check the log for knowing exactly the reason for the failure.

```
forever logs
```